# CakePHP savefield() with out knowing the record's id

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

How can I update a single field without knowing the record's ID? I have the user's username and I don't want to waste resources by doing a query just to get the id.

Note: I know I can achieve this with `updateAll()` but that seams like over kill, but is there a better way?

Can I some how limit `updateAll()` to only search for one record and then finish, because I don't want it to continue to search when there is only one possible match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`updateAll()` is the way to go in this case.

All the other save methods require the ID to be known.

You could also use the `query()` method :  `$this->Model->query($sql)`

However, remember that values are not automatically escaped in this method.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on `query()` not escaping. I will just stick with `updateAll()` unless I notice a performance issue.

Comment: `updateAll()` is the best option, `query()` should be avoided as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Cake (or pretty much any other framework), you're sacrificing some efficiency with unnecessary queries.  However, you can still run custom queries.  For example, if you know the username and are trying to update the first_name field, you can do the following:

```
$this->User->query("UPDATE users SET first_name = '$new_firstname' WHERE username = '$username'");
```

Comment: It's because of that efficiency sacrificing that I am trying to make my querying as efficient as possible. Thanks for your input!